# change button appearance depending on input

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have an input group as below:

```
  <div class="input-group" xmlns="">
    <input #searchField autofocus type="text" class="form-control"
           [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (keyup.enter)="doSearch(searchValue)">
    <button class="btn-primary fa fa-search" id="search-icon"
            (click)="doSearch(searchValue)"></button>
  </div>
```

I want the button to be disabled until the user inputs something in the search field. As soon as the user types something in the search field, I want to change the appearance of the button from an icon to just text i.e. 'Search'.

I've tried using `(change)=someFunction()` on the input element, but I'm not sure how to use this to alter the button properties. Is there a specific directive I can use to achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a reference to your control, say #searchVAlue, then check if it is `dirty` or `touched` to show either a `button` or a `span` (`p`, `div`,etc.).

```
  <div class="input-group" xmlns="">
    <input #searchField autofocus type="text" class="form-control"
           [(ngModel)]="searchValue" #sv="ngModel" (keyup.enter)="doSearch(searchValue)">
    <button *ngIf="(sv.dirty || sv.touched)" class="btn-primary fa fa-search" id="search-icon"
            (click)="doSearch(searchValue)"></button>
    <span *ngIf="!(sv.dirty || sv.touched)">Your text here</span>

  </div>
```

You can see the implementation [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/uB3GeRgzVZKestpOCu2N?p=preview).

Comment: This is almost where I want it to be. Is there any way for the button to disappear if the input field becomes empty? i.e. if I enter something, and then delete what i entered. The button still remains when it should disappear.

Comment: add `|| searchValue` to your conditions. If you want to show it if `searchValue` input is empty add `!searchValue` and if you want to show it if  it has value add `searchValue`

Comment: That only works for the first time i load the page, but after the page loads, if I type something in the text field the button will appear. Now if i delete what i typed, the button still remains when it shouldn't. Could you update your implementation to show this?

Comment: @user141834 Just say exactly when you want the button to be shown and when the text?

Comment: For now lets just worry about the button. The button should be shown as long as the input field is not empty. If the input field is empty, then the button should not be shown.

Comment: @user141834 Check the link again, the part after this heading `After OP's comment`